# Get weather from Yahoo with jQuery

Tags: jquery, geolocation, weather, weather-api, yahoo-weather-api

I'm using the Google API to get a user's location on [this site](http://www.chris-armstrong.com/whispers). How would I go about getting the weather for that user from Yahoo or somewhere?

**UPDATE**: Ok so I'm going with Yahoo, but I've never done an HTTP GET request before. Im using jQuery and the following code:

```
function getWeather () {
            $.get("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2502265", function(data){
               alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
             });
        }
```

However, the alert is only returning "Data loaded", and the rest is blank, so I'm doing something wrong but not sure what.

Also, I need a way of taking my latitude and longitude and fiding the WOEID for them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617912/yahoo-weather-api-json-icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about Yahoo Weather, you can pass the location as parameter to their API url and it will give you the result:

http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

Comment: Thanks. It says I need to send through a WOEID... how do I find my WOEID from lat/lon?

Comment: You can either switch to their Geo location API or use some of the workarounds here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093358/receive-a-woeid-by-lat-long-with-yahoos-api

Comment: Updated my question there with some sample jQuery code, don't suppose you'd know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Since Yahoo is using Weather Channel data I guess you can directly hook up with them - http://www.weather.com/services/xmloap.html