# How to get outdoors temperature on Bash?

Tags: bash, geolocation, temperature

I need to write a script on bash and on python that will receive temperature from outdoors using geolocation methods.
I remind that when I actively used Ubuntu, I had a snippet or something like. It received from somewhere outdoor temperature, wind directrion, wind speed and etc.
 I guess it would great for my script if exist some public API of this.
 And I am sure SO community knows it. Share, please =)

Comment: Check out https://coderwall.com/p/gc1vpq. It does exactly what you want if you don't mind getting an API key for Wunderground. Translating the PHP code to Python should be easy enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

Your python script will probably:

1. Interface with `http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2442047&u=f` where `w=` is your WOEID
2. Parse XML using available python libraries
3. Display desired output

Or (BASH):

1. Download the xml through bash (`wget`)
2. Use `grep`/`awk`/`sed` to extract desired information
3. Display in terminal

*Edit:

just messed around with it in bash.  This will extract the Temperature.  Im sure you can clean it up.

```
#!/bin/bash

wget http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2502265 -O test.xml > /dev/null 2>&1
TEMP=$(grep "yweather:condition" test.xml | cut -d"=" -f4 | cut -d"\"" -f2)
echo "Temperature: " $TEMP
rm -rf test.xml
```

Calculate your WOEID easily here:  http://isithackday.com/geoplanet-explorer/

Comment: Nice. I like it. A powerfull thing. I'm just not sure in sended temp data. For example: New-York town from USA has many WOEID. I don't know how to determine the correctly for my IP. Need thinking about. Anyway it would work perfectly for me if I'll bind WOEID by myself.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you.  I learned a bit myself!  Anyway, I checked SO and there was a similar question on calculating WOEID.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093358/receive-a-woeid-by-lat-long-with-yahoos-api     It appears yahoo has provided the means to do so already.